# Regular expression formatting?

Tags: perl, formatting

I want ask for some help in Perl formatting. I have three lines like next:

```
Function SaveOfflineData Started                                 0012345671  439                                                                              
Offline data not found in BEHAV_DATA for PartyId = 1054          0012345671  439                                                           
Offline data not found in RE_PARTY_LOAN_CONTRACT for PartyId = 1 0012345671  439
```

There are three rows as I have, and I need to filter first text (put it in variable) second number (`0012345671` - put it in variable) and last ID also save it into variable. But I am not able to set proper regular expression to format first text string. Anybody knows?

Comment: `my ( $text, $number, $id ) = $row =~ m/^(.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/`

Comment: It looks like you have fixed-width data, which means you'd be better off using `unpack` or `substr` for this.

Comment: What information are you trying to capture from the "first text"?

Comment: @fugu No. Biffen's code works like a charm. I tried it out.

Comment: Thank you Biffen. I have to said that I need to use clear perl without modules at the beginning . Becouse next step is filtering by regular expression in Eclipse - Agent Builder and generating Agents. But your version works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This problem becomes trivial when you use the right tool for the job. And the right tool for this job, as it turns out, is not regular expressions---it's [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html). See [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) for an introduction to `pack` and `unpack`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = unpack('A65 A12 A*');
    print Dumper(\@fields);
}

__DATA__
Function SaveOfflineData Started                                 0012345671  439
Offline data not found in BEHAV_DATA for PartyId = 1054          0012345671  439
Offline data not found in RE_PARTY_LOAN_CONTRACT for PartyId = 1 0012345671  439
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Function SaveOfflineData Started',
          '0012345671',
          '439'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'Offline data not found in BEHAV_DATA for PartyId = 1054',
          '0012345671',
          '439'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'Offline data not found in RE_PARTY_LOAN_CONTRACT for PartyId = 1',
          '0012345671',
          '439'
        ];
```